# How can we convert a string to int for very large integer values?

Tags: c, linux, char, int

I have used the function `atoi` to convert character strings to `int` and it's working fine but when I gave

```
num = atoi (argv[1]) ;

// argv contain 4294967295 maximun value of 32 bit integer
```

it's giving me 2147483647 answer which is basically half of 4294967295

i guess that its because of difference of bytes in `char` and `int`.
Can any one explain whats happening to bits and bytes 
and how to fix it or convert it to int

Comment: 2147483647 is a maximum value of signed int (from -2147483648 to 2147483647). Which is used there as return value. Your value is maximum value of unsigned int (which has range from 0 to 4294967295).

Comment: Apart from sscanf suggested below, you can also take `long` instead of `int` and then use `strtol()` or `strtoul()`.

Comment: Do you want to convert ***a*** char to a int (i.e. represent the value of a particular `char` in a `int`) or so you mean to interpret part of a ***string*** as representing a decimal value? You question title is closer to the former, but your example code is doing the latter.

Comment: @dmckee sir i want string to convert to int my string is basically give as command line  argument

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've run into the maximum value of an integer. Since `atoi` returns an `int`, it is limited to the size of an integer on your machine. It looks like your machine uses 32-bit `int`s.

In case you missed it (it's easy to miss), 2147483647 = (2 ^ 31) - 1. Remember that `int`s can be negative, and the leftmost bit is the sign bit in that case. That's why you see the number being "limited" to 2147483647.

Try defining `num` as `unsigned int` instead of `int`, and use `strtoul` instead of `atoi`.

Comment: That alone doesn't help since `atoi` has UB for values outside the range of `int`. You need `strtoul` or similar.

Comment: This is true. I updated my answer accordingly. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @ZachRattner: `stroul` is not a standard function as far as I know :)

Comment: @Mat: It is. Check the C standard (ISO 9899, you can find it via Google), section 7.20.1.4.

Comment: To clarify for readers: `stroul` was a typo. `strtoul` is perfectly standard.

Answer (score 2):

Use `strtoul` instead of `atoi`. The latter results in undefined behavior if the value overflows `int`, which is what happens in your case.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to handle seriously **very large** numbers [then you need a library like GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

GMP stands for GNU Multiple Precision and it is a BigNum library, which means it has code to handle integers bigger than 32 bits or 64 bits. It can handle as many bits as you have RAM.

To convert a string into an integer you would use the GMP function `mpz_set_str()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtoull` for very long numbers.

```
unsigned long long int strtoull(const char *nptr, char **endptr,
                                       int base);
```

Compile with C99 support `-std=c99` or provide the defines in `man strtoull` to get the definition.