# how to check whether a number entered from keyboard isnumeric in c?

Tags: c

can anyone help in know how to check whether a number entered from keyboard isnumeric in c?

I tried

```
isdigit
```

Comment: `isdigit(c)`, where `c` represents a single character, is correct.. if you're checking a single character..

Answer (score 4):

You can use [strtol](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol)

Just pass a second parameter different from `NULL` :

> If endptr is not NULL, strtol() stores the address of the first
>   invalid character in *endptr. If there were no digits at all, strtol()
>   stores the original value of nptr in *endptr (and returns 0). In
>   particular, if *nptr is not '\0' but **endptr is '\0' on return, the
>   entire string is valid.

You can also see `strtoull` for large unsigned integer number, or `strtof`, `strtod`, `strtold` to check for decimal number.

If you're parsing very large number, the best solution is to read character by character, checking the value, and store it at each step in an appropriate data structure.

But keep in mind that is if you try this solution, you would have to use an extern library to handle big numbers, or rewrite the part you need with the constraints it involves.

Comment: Correct for most use cases, but you may want to be careful with this. See, for instance [How can we convert a string to int for very large integer values?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7697637/2509). How you test depends on exactly *what you want to **do*** with the result.

Answer (score 1):

After quick google search:

You can use `ctype.h` for building function like this:

```
int isnumeric(char *str)
{
  while(*str)
  {
    if(!isdigit(*str))
      return 0;
    str++;
  }

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: I don't think decimal points ('.') or other locale-specific separators  will pass that test. For example, "0.5" will fail (which I'd consider strictly numeric) - and "1,000" will fail as well (which may or may not be considered "numeric").

Comment: the number entered from keyboard is a int type not char type.

Comment: I was thinking just about testing if `char*` is representation of `int` type. Also, i would consider usage of `scanf`, for integers or decimals.

Comment: @user7: What you get from the keyboard is a series of characters. It's not a `int` until you make it one. This is c and that means you are living close to the metal.

Comment: @user7 You should really tell us more about how you obtain this input and why isdigit didn't work for you. Normally you'd just do int c = getchar(); if (c != EOF && isdigit(c)) { puts("That's a digit");} should do.